# Beginner SQL IF Clause in Django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I need to be able to handle a `Division By Zero` Error in Django. The following SQL is causing it:

```
select *, (available_credit * 100 / credit_limit)::integer as percent_available from
(SELECT
  a.id,
```

On the first line, `credit limit` for people will sometimes be 0, and I want to be able to handle that scenario so that the resulting `percent_available` variable can be 0.

I tried to find a fix with my little known SQL but it obviously doesn't work:

```
IF (credit_limit = 0)
  0::integer as percent_available from
ELSE
  (available_credit * 100 / credit_limit)::integer as percent_available from
(SELECT
  a.id,
```

Is there a feasible way to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the ORM?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CASE, WHEN for this if you are writing raw sql and getting the output is rather easy but django calls for a bit of work.

```
SELECT A.*, CASE WHEN credit_limit = 0 THEN 10000
ELSE
  (available_credit * 100 / credit_limit)::integer 
END as percent_available from
(SELECT
  a.id, ....) AS A
```

It would be wholly incorrect to report available percentage as zero when credit_limit is zero. You shoudl report it to the user as N/A or something else.

Getting back to django, you would use the [CASE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) expression for this.

> A Case() expression is like the if ... elif ... else statement in
>   Python. Each condition in the provided When() objects is evaluated in
>   order, until one evaluates to a truthful value. The result expression
>   from the matching When() object is returned.

Now suppose your model was named Credit, then the query might be.

```
Credit.objects.all().annotate(credit_available = 
   Case(
     When(credit_limit = 0, Then value 10000)
     default = F('available_credit')*100/F('credit_limit'))
 )
```

Comment: thank you, and why did you use the value `10000` after the `THEN` clause?

Comment: To distinguish from the sitation when the available_credit = 0 in this case available_credit * 100 / credit_limit will be 0.  But this is a very different situation from having credit_limit = 0

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE`

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN (credit_limit = 0) THEN /* code */ ELSE /* code */ END AS
percent_available FROM ...
```