# How to Add Temporary Attribute to Django Querysets and then Merge

Tags: python, django, list, filter, django-queryset

So I am trying to add a temporary attribute to two separate QuerySets from the same model, but it seems that as soon as I try to merge them together, the new fields disappear.

Example:

```
class IndexView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        q1 = MyModel.objects.filter(points=0)
        q2 = MyModel.objects.filter(points=100)

        for q in q1:
            q.title = 'Loser'
            print(q.title)  # Prints 'Loser'

        for q in q2:
            q.title = 'Winner'
            print(q.title)  # Prints 'Winner'

        q = q1 | q2  # Merges the two QuerySets together

        for item in q:
            print(item.title)  # ERROR: "Title" is not a field anymore apparently...

        return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

I have tried another approach that uses `.chain()` (mentioned in another thread), but that changes the type from `QuerySet` to `List`, which I do not want. I will post it below. Is there any way to keep the list as a QuerySet while achieving the same results? Please note that I want the `title` attribute to be temporary so I can separate items in the template. Also, the `points` filter is not the actual filter and is actually a lot more complicated, so template tags and model methods are not an option.

```
from itertools import chain
feed = sorted(
    chain(q1, q2),
    key=lambda instance: instance.created)
```

`Django v1.9.6` `Python v3.4.3`

Comment: `q = q1 | q2` This creates a brand new queryset, that will select the union of what `q1` and `q2` would. When you then go through `q`, you trigger a new query and load objects from the database again.

Comment: Interesting - so is there an alternative approach that would avoid wiping the temporary attributes I defined?

Comment: Ideally, you would add those attributes as part of the query itself, using `annotate`, perhaps with a `Case` clause. You wouldn't even need the two querysets and the merge, just explain the database how to calculate the field by itself.

Comment: Or, since this is a really simple calculation, do it in a model method or even directly in the template: `{% if q.points == 0 %}loser{else %}winner{% endif %}`. Again, then you only need a single query.

Comment: @spectras: Hmmm I'm not sure how to go about that. Again, this is sample code, my actual code uses `GenericRelations` to `GenericForeignKeys` in the filtering process, so it get's a bit too crazy. I'd like to hear more about annotations if that's a viable option.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I would love to do that, but as I mentioned the actual code is a fair bit more complex, so using simple `if` conditions is not an option.

Comment: ̀annotate` logic probably won't be that helpful then, unless you're willing to create a stored procedure on the database side

Comment: Yeah I definitely don't want additions to the DB, especially since the attributes I am adding are relative to the logged in user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beginner SQL IF Clause in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141743/beginner-sql-if-clause-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can do this, because when you do:

```
q = q1 | q2
```

You were executing a new database query. There's no straightforward way for this, you could only query them all together then mark then respectively:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(points=0) | Q(points=100))
for item in queryset:
    if q.points  == 0:
        q.title = 'Loser'
    elif q.points == 100:
        q.title = 'Winner'
```

Given that you might have complicated condition about `points`, you could also create a method for model `MyModel` then call that function to return a value similar to assign `title` to it.

Comment: Can you also tell me why you don't want to convert them into lists? You've already looped through them so there's no real benefit to keep it as queryset, right?

Comment: Moreso in case I need to use filters or templatetags in the future, which may need access to QuerySet methods.

Comment: Then do the filters in the views as much as you can instead of templatetags and convert them into list. I still believe that template could get the final data if you process everything in views.py method.

Comment: @Hybrid> All QuerySet methods return new querysets (or plain objects). This means setting attributes on objects won't work. You're down to `annotate` with potential db-side function, or make it a [property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193556/how-do-python-properties-work)

Comment: @ShangWang: That's what I guess will happen in the end, unfortunately it seems there's no way around that

Comment: @spectras: I appreciate the information, so I guess I have no choice but to keep it this way until there is the possibility of an alternative non-db-altering solution.